# Web API not being recognized on my machine

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I've pulled down a project onto my my machine that is using Web API. When I look at the nugget window it shows that I have `web api 2.2`, the web host, the core libraries, the client libraries, the cross origin support, and `Data v 1-3`.

However, when I try to build the project, I'm given the following errors:

> The type or namespace name 'Cors' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.Http' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>   and
>
> The type or namespace name 'HttpApplication' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Any help you guys and gals can give will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you added a reference to those DLLs?

Comment: I believer this question isn't hard enough to drop it here in SO. Do you really need help to just add the proper assembly references to your project...?

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer since when is an option for Off Topic "This question is too easy and everyone on the planet should know the answer already?"

Comment: Back on topic, which version of the .Net Framework and which Visual Studio version are you running?

Comment: Both of the namespaces are referenced in my project (System.Web, System.Web.Http) but it occurred to me that they might not be the right ones, so I looked in References>Assemblies>Extensions, and added the System.Web I found there, and that error was gone. But the Cors error is still there and I don't see another System.Web.Http to reference.

Comment: 4.5, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate

Comment: @AndrewCounts It's not about "too easy", it's about: *take your time, put your effort*. Just imagine if everyone would drop a question whenever some project reference is missing or wrong.................

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer, I understand how to check for references. It's really about being unfamiliar with web api, seeing the namespaces I'm being told are missing, and knowing that the exact same solution builds for other people. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @WillMartin That's the issue: you think you're right because *others could build the same solution*. What if you copied the solution in a wrong way so there're missing files? Or whatever. This isn't about WebAPI: it's a common issue when building any project...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had the same issue after I had Resharper add the CORS reference.

I fixed it by adding the correct nuget packages: `Microsoft.AspNet.Cors` and `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors`.

Comment: in my case, I already had those installed but just to be sure I've reinstalled them and the error got fixed.